# How to upload video with other images?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a website using directorist plugin on wordpress and by default on add listing form directorist only accept images and not videos for the listing slider.
I tried to check their fiels and there is a file named
image_upload.php in which theres an object and inside the object i have  a key of type and a property of all available formats so what I did is I just added 'mp4' in that object and that object and hoped that things will work fine and yep they did
i was able to upload the video but on backend I got an error and when i upload the listing with a video it didnt got the images as well and returned empty array

any help?

Comment: You should tag your question with WordPress and Directorist - it may attract the right people who can best answer to it.

Comment: And we are developers, so an essay is ok, but we always prefer to see the code you are telling us about

Comment: $img_upload_data = [
 'type'               => 'jpg, jpeg, png, gif',
 'max_num_of_img'     => $limit,
 'max_total_img_size' => $max_total_file_size_kb,
 'is_required'        => $required,
 'max_size_per_img'   => $max_file_size_kb,
];

this is the object which is in image_upload.php file and on frontend file it have
$listing->get_slider_template();

Comment: You need to [edit] your question when you have relevant code or other updates. As you can see its hard to read in the comments, and it's separated from the other info

Comment: The fact that this script file was named `image_upload`, and not just `media_upload` or `file_upload`, is probably a pretty good indicator that this whole thing might simply not be set up to work with videos. Just because your manipulation allowed you to _upload_ a video now, doesn't mean the rest of the code is prepared to _handle_ a video. It might, for example, use `getimagesize` to try and determine the dimensions of the _image_ it is expecting, and fails at that point when the current item is _not_ an image.

Comment: if one of you can personally help me by a google or zoom meeting I will be really thankful to him/her.
please reach me
jasghar186@gmail.com
wa.me/923266328517

just a little meeting so I can fix this issue thanks